# Setting background image on Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm reading a Word template file that I process in my code.

I want to set the background image of said document. Here's how I'm doing it

```cs
ImagePart ip = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg, "ImageBackground");
Stream streamImage = ip.GetStream();

BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(streamImage);
bw.Write(imageArray);
bw.Close();

DocumentBackground docBg = new DocumentBackground() { Color = "FFFFFF" };
V.Background bg = new V.Background()
{
    Id = "_x0000_s1025",
    BlackWhiteMode = V.Office.BlackAndWhiteModeValues.White,
    TargetScreenSize = V.Office.ScreenSizeValues.Sz1024x768
};

V.Fill fill = new V.Fill()
{
    RelationshipId = "ImageBackground",
    Title = "background",
    Recolor = true,
    Type = V.FillTypeValues.Frame
};

bg.Append(fill);
docBg.Append(bg);

mainPart.Document.InsertAt(docBg, 0);
```

The generated XML matches perfectly to what's created by Word when you set the background manually.

Yet, when I open the generated file, the background is not working.

Also, one weird thing is that when I use Word to export the document as an HTML (As soon as the editor switches to HTML content), the render updates in Word and the background is working but when opening the file again, no longer in HTML mode, it disappear again.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in Word

Comment: That's what I thought... But it's weird that the exact same code generated by word himself works...

Comment: If you do a binary compare between your document and the one created by word, is there a difference?

Comment: @NathanJ does my solution below work for you? If not, can you send me your resulting Word document so that I can investigate it?

Comment: I'm back at work tomorrow, I'll tell you then. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<w:displayBackgroundShape/>` to the "settings.xml" part.
So, try using the following:

```
var settings = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings;
settings.DisplayBackgroundShape = new DisplayBackgroundShape();
```